# Prefer variables inside or outside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

Lets say I have an anonymous function that needs a few variables to keep track of its state. The function works the same with the variables inside or outside the anonymous function. Are there any performance or other considerations when deciding where to define the variables?

For example. Is there any reason to prefer this

```
function fn () {
  let i = 0
  return something(cb => {
    setInterval(() => cb(i++), 1000)
  })
}
```

over this

```
function fn () {
  return something(cb => {
    let i = 0
    setInterval(() => cb(i++), 1000)
  })
}
```

These aren't functionally identical if the anonymous function is called multiple times but for the sake of argument lets say it will only be called once.

Comment: In general, variables should have the smallest scope they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference worth worrying about is in terms of code maintainability. Generally, [variables should live in the smallest scope possible](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388052/rationale-to-prefer-local-variables-over-instance-variables). This can make the code easier to read. For example:

> These aren't functionally identical if the anonymous function is called multiple times but for the sake of argument lets say it will only be called once.

Without you *explicitly saying that*, a reader of the code would likely think that there's at least a possibility of `fn` being called more than once (otherwise, what's the point of the outer scope variable?).

Or, imagine if there was more code in the function: compare

```
function fn () {
  // a moderate amount of code
  return something(cb => {
    // a moderate amount of code
    let i = 0
    setInterval(() => cb(i++), 1000)
  })
}
```

to

```
function fn () {
  let i = 0
  // a moderate amount of code
  return something(cb => {
    // a moderate amount of code
    setInterval(() => cb(i++), 1000)
  })
}
```

The first version is probably preferable, because the declaration of the variable is very close to where it's being used, which is not the case for the second version.

Another difference between them is that, the farther up the scope chain the interpreter has to look to find a variable reference, the longer it'll take to process, at least in some circumstances. This is completely insignificant in almost all cases, but it's still a potential difference: compare https://jsfiddle.net/pa2v9xuj/ to https://jsfiddle.net/wzo7bgve/